# Python Function Error with Deep LS recursion generator

Tags: python, databricks, apache-atlas

I have the following function that should do a recursion on all data lake assets, however it is giving me the following error  `TypeError: <generator object deep_ls at 0x7fc512538e40> has the wrong type - (<class 'str'>,) is expected.` when calling the following line `files = dbutils.fs.ls(deep_ls(root, max_depth=20))` which is meant to get the files recursively. Do you have any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this:

```
def deep_ls(path: str, max_depth=1):


    # Hidden files may be filtered out
    condition = None if keep_hidden else lambda x: x.name[0] not in ('_', '.')

    # List all files in path and apply sorting rules
    li = sorted(filter(condition, dbutils.fs.ls(path)),reverse=reverse, key=key)

    # Return all files (not ending with '/')
    for x in li:
        if x.path[-1] != '/':
            yield x

    # If the max_depth has not been reached, start
    # listing files and folders in subdirectories
    if max_depth > 1:
        for x in li:
            if x.path[-1] != '/':
                continue
            for y in deep_ls(x.path, max_depth - 1, reverse, key, keep_hidden):
                yield y

    # If max_depth has been reached,
    # return the folders
    else:
        for x in li:
            if x.path[-1] == '/':
                yield x
            

def key(val):
    try:
        return int(list(filter(bool, val.path.split('/'))).pop().split('=').pop())
    except ValueError as e:
        return -1
```

Here is the full databricks notebook code that is trying to call this function:

```
    # Example Implementation
# ----------------------

# Library Imports

import os
import requests
import json
import jmespath
import pandas as pd

from pprint import pprint
from pyapacheatlas.auth import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
from pyapacheatlas.core import PurviewClient, AtlasEntity, AtlasProcess, TypeCategory
from pyapacheatlas.core.typedef import *

from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Authentication

# Service Principal with "Purview Data Source Administrator" permissions on Purview
tenant_id = "enter-tenant-id"
client_id = "enter-client-id"
client_secret = "enter-client-secret"
resource_url = "https://purview.azure.net"
data_catalog_name = "demo-purview"
adls_sas_token = 'enter-sas-token-here'

# Retrieve authentication objects
azuread_access_token = azuread_auth(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret, resource_url)
purview_client = purview_auth(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret, data_catalog_name)

# Asset details

# Asset parameters
storage_account = "adls"
container = "lake"

# The root level path we want to begin populating assets from
top_path = f"/azure_storage_account#{storage_account}.core.windows.net/azure_datalake_gen2_service#{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/azure_datalake_gen2_filesystem#{container}"

# Retrieve full list of assets
assets_all = list(get_all_adls_assets(top_path, data_catalog_name, azuread_access_token, max_depth=20))


# Grab SAS token
#adls_sas_token = dbutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds(linked_service_name)

# Configure Spark to access from DFS endpoint
root = 'https://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/' % (container, storage_account)

spark.conf.set('fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.dfs.core.windows.net' % (container, storage_account), adls_sas_token)
print('Remote adls root path: ' + root)

# Get ADLS files recursively
files = dbutils.fs.ls(deep_ls(root, max_depth=20))
files_df = convertfiles2df(files) # Note this is a Pandas DataFrame

# Generate asset-aligned names
files_df['asset'] = files_df['name'].str.replace(r'\d+', '{N}')

# Append schema row-wise from Purview
files_df['schema'] = files_df.apply(lambda row: get_adls_asset_schema(assets_all, row['asset'], purview_client), axis=1)

# Display Asset DataFrame
display(files_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dbutils.fs.ls` function [accepts only one argument](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#ls-command-dbutilsfsls) - string with the path, but you're passing to it the generator instead.  You may convert it to something like this:

```py
for file in deep_ls(root, max_depth=20):
  res = dbutils.fs.ls(file)
  do_something_with_result...
```

Comment: I have tried that but still seeing the same error.